# Realistic Shapeshifter Attempt

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, reproduction

Imagine a sessile, multi-cellular slime like organism (or whatever necessary) awaits in a burrow or along a tree branch. Then an animal lands in its ooze and is trapped and soon paralyzed by its venom like secretions. Then the shapeshifter envelops the creature, digesting it completely and obtaining the prey's DNA through horizontal gene transfer. It then creates a womb-like cocoon, creating either a clone of the original creature, or its body, and uses this more mobile form to spread itself across the environment. Is this method of reproduction feasible, and what problems would the shapeshifter encounter?

Edit: The shapeshifter would reproduce itself asexually by regurgitating part of itself into a suitable location.

(I know there are simpler ways to accomplish this, but I felt this was an approach towards shapeshifting I haven't seen before)

Comment: Reproduction cycles need to be...  a cycle.  You are missing the step where the slime-child animal somehow transforms into it's parent's slime form.  As it now stands, you have no answer to the question, "where do slime-form sessiles come from?"

Comment: @Henry Taylor I edited my question to clarify its reproduction cycle. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure I get what this organism is doing because it sounds as if it wasting A LOT of energy for nothing. It eats an organism, then recreates this very organism via a completely new womb (the most inefficient thing I've ever heard) just to get someplace? Why doesn't it just take over the organism? You state yourself that there are simpler ways of doing this, so you are aware that this is not the smartest approach to the topic. Could you perhaps state what exactly you want to have checked and what is just part of the premise and you are ok with not making sense?

Comment: I know there are simpler ways of accomplishing what it is setting out to do, but I've attempted to create conditions for a biologically plausible "shapeshifter." I wanted to know if its method of reproduction is feasible. @Raditz_35

Comment: Thanks @FoxElemental I'm not a fan of typing questions out from my phone!

Comment: You may consider making this post a part of the [Anatomically Correct series of questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series).  You would need to be sure you met all the requirements, but it would make a fine addition.

Comment: @JBH Once I improve my question, how would i do that?

Comment: There are detailed directions at the Meta site I linked to.  Adjust your question to meet the requirements (if it is needed).  Adjust your title to conform with the others that you see there.  Edit the answer at the linked site to add a link to your question with others.  And I recommend adding a link to that site to your own question (look at one or two of the latest ACS questions, you will see what I mean).

Comment: Have you checked out our [tag:shapeshifters] tag?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @Michael Kjörling I hadn't seen it!

Answer (score 1):

Your shapeshifter has no reason to re-create an animal once it has consumed it. It could however change its appearance to appear like an animal to attract it closer into its reach so it can get an easy meal. Imagine it like a Ditto from pokemon... inside the day care...but it eats the other pokemon instead of.. you know...making eggs.

Comment: So @Shadowzee, you are proposing a more mimic approach, maybe it remembers prey's habits and breeding seasons and then imitates a mating call and catches an easy meal! I like it!

Comment: @Thalassan Yeah, although I wouldn't call it a mimic because that term reminds me of the chest with teeth that attacks people who open it.

Comment: Fair enough lol